# access ajax data in closure

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to populate a "private" variable in my function with some data loaded by ajax, so it can be accessed within the function. What I currently have:

```
var foo = (function(){

    var ajaxData;

    var useAjaxData = function(data){

    };

})();
```

I suppose that I need to do something similar to this, since it's an async call? Are there any prettier solutions for this?

```
var foo = (function(){

    $.ajax({
       url: 'something',
       success: function(data){

           var ajaxData = data;

           var useAjaxData = function(data){

           };
      }
    });

})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that because ajax is asynchronous, you can't depend on when the ajax request completes (or even completing at all), and thus when the ajax callback is fired.  So this can never be depended on:

```
var ajaxData;
$.ajax().done(function (data) { ajaxData = data; });
useAjaxData(ajaxData);
```

That is to say that ***all*** of your code that relies on the ajax data has to be done in the ajax callbacks.

As for your specific question about whether it can be made *prettier*, that's really a matter of opinion, but instead of using `success:` you may prefer to use Deferred methods.

```
var jqxhr = $.ajax();
/* millions of lines of code */
jqxhr.done(function (data) {
    // work with the ajax data
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Just put the data variable in the top closure:

```
var foo = (function() {
  var ajaxData; // accessible in the anonymous function and any nested function

  function useAjaxData() {
    // `ajaxData` is accessible from here, 
    // but will be undefined until the server response has been handled
    doSomethingWith(ajaxData);
  }

  $.ajax({
    // ...
    success: function(data) {
      // note: no `var` here, the outer `ajaxData` variable will be used
      ajaxData = data; 
    }
  });
}());
```

This works, because the `ajaxData` variable is not declared (with `var`) in the scope of the success handler. It will therefore be looked up (and set) in the surrounding scopes. Only if it wasn’t declared at all, an implicit global variable would be created.